# Площади треугольников

Tags: c, функции

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с кодом.

> Даны координаты вершин двух треугольников, требуется определить их площади и вывести номер треугольника, площадь которого больше.
>
> Со стандартного устройства ввода вводятся через пробел координаты шести точек:
>
> `Ax`, `Ay`, `Bx`, `By`, `Сx`, `Сy`, `Dx`, `Dy`, `Ex`, `Ey`, `Fx`, `Fy`,
>
> где точки A, B, C —вершины первого треугольника, а точки D, E, F — вершины второго.
>
> Координаты всех точек являются вещественными из диапазона от -1000 до 1000, заданными с тремя знаками после запятой.
>
> Требуется вывести «1»(без кавычек), если площадь первого треугольника больше либо равна площади второго, иначе требуется вывести «2»(без кавычек).
>
> **Input**
>
> `1.000 1.000 1.000 3.000 4.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 6.000 7.000 1.000`
>
> **Output**
>
> **2**
>
> Примечание
> Используйте спецификатор «%f» для ввода вещественных чисел.
> Гарантируется, что площади каждого из треугольников больше нуля.
> Сравнивать вещественные числа требуется с погрешность 0.001, а это значит:
> число A будет равно числу B с точностью до 0.001, когда `abs(A-B) <= 0.001`, где `abs(A-B)`
> возвращает абсолютное значение (A-B), то есть `max(A, B) - min(A, B)`.
>
> Площадь треугольника по координатам его вершин можно найти следующим образом:
>
> `S = | (Bx - Ax) * (Ay + By) + (Cx - Bx) * (Cy + By) + (Ax - Cx) * (Ay + Cy)| / 2`

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
    float Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy,Ex,Ey,Fx,Fy, s1, s2;
    scanf("%3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f %3f", &Ax,&Ay,&Bx,&By,&Cx,&Cy,&Dx,&Dy,&Ex,&Ey,&Fx,&Fy);
    s1=abs((Bx-Ax)*(Ay+By)+(Cx-Bx)*(Cy+By)+(Ax-Cx)*(Ay+Cy))/2;
    s2=abs((Ex-Dx)*(Dy+Ey)+(Fx-Ex)*(Fy+Ey)+(Dx-Fx)*(Dy+Fy))/2;
    if(s1>=s2) printf("1");
    else printf("2");
    return 0;
    }
```

Программа по логике должна работать корректно, но при введении чисел из примера выводится 1, а не 2

Comment: Может, все же будете сравнивать с учетом требуемой точности?

Comment: Нужно вывести больший треугольник, а вы вместо этого выводите меньший треугольник. Ну и вместо int нужен float конечно же

Comment: И еще - вы бы формулы-то правильно вводили... `(Fx-Ex)*(Fy-Ey)` - дальше продолжать? Интересно, вы хоть минут 20 пробовали просматривать свой код **критично**, а не просто тыча клавиши - а вдруг сработает?... Типичный вопрос на закрытие как очепятка...

Comment: Вы бы дали URL проверяющей системы, это бы сняло много вопросов - можно было бы проверить свой код и убедиться в его правильности, прежде чем давать ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка (маленькая) заключалась в том, что вы неправильно задавали форматирование при вводе значений. Вы писали %3f а ширина поля, на самом деле, была 5(!). В результате координаты вводились неверно и дальнейший расчёт давал полную чепуху.

Ошибки (большие) я увидел так:

1. Вы **не** оформили расчёт площади как функцию
2. Вы **не** проверяли введённые значения

Подправленный код выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float area(float Ax, float Ay, float Bx, float By, float Cx, float Cy) {
    return abs((Bx-Ax)*(Ay+By)+(Cx-Bx)*(Cy+By)+(Ax-Cx)*(Ay+Cy))/2;
}

int main() {
    float Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy,Ex,Ey,Fx,Fy, s1, s2;
    scanf("%5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f", 
           &Ax,&Ay,&Bx,&By,&Cx,&Cy,&Dx,&Dy,&Ex,&Ey,&Fx,&Fy);
    printf("Первый треугольник: (%6.3f,%6.3f), (%6.3f,%6.3f), (%6.3f,%6.3f)\n", Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy);
    printf("Второй треугольник: (%6.3f,%6.3f), (%6.3f,%6.3f), (%6.3f,%6.3f)\n", Dx,Dy,Ex,Ey,Fx,Fy);

    s1 = area(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy);
    s2 = area(Dx,Dy,Ex,Ey,Fx,Fy);

    printf("s1 = %8.3f\n", s1);
    printf("s2 = %8.3f\n", s2);

    if(s1>=s2) printf("1\n");
    else printf("2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт "2" :-)

Comment: Отладочный вывод треугольников только потом при сдаче не забыть закомментировать :) И еще - ваше `%5f` тоже будет сбоить - ведь значения до 1000 с тремя знаками после точки, вот и считайте... Зачем вообще что-то ставить перед `f`, если числа отделены пробелами?

Comment: @Harry - "Зачем вообще что-то ставить перед f ?"
- Если Вы вводите одну строку - смысла в этом не много. Но:
- Традиция явно задавать ширину поля ввода возникла ещё в те далёкие времена, когда данные набивали на перфокартах, зачастую специальными машинами - табуляторами. Это нашло отражение в операторах ввода в таких древних языках, как Cobol и Fortran.
И смысл в этом есть вполне определённый и сегодня: если у Вас данные занимают сотни, а то и тысячи строк, то гораздо легче их контролировать, если они набиты в выравненные колонки.

Comment: Ну, `%5f` - не годится в любом случае... Но даже если это большие таблицы - то `%f`позволит считать верно, а вот с определенной шириной может и сбойнуть. Результат - ошибка в форматировании не помешает программе отработать верно, а вот с шириной поля - приведет к трудно обнаруживаемой ошибке...

Answer (score 1):

Мои 5 копеек.

1. Даже в условии явно написано, что спецификатор чтения - `%f`. Не `%3f`, не `%5f` , а именно `%f`...
2. В условии явно указано, что при отличии менее чем на 0.001 площади считаются одинаковыми.

А потому

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy,Ex,Ey,Fx,Fy, s1, s2;
    scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f",
          &Ax,&Ay,&Bx,&By,&Cx,&Cy,&Dx,&Dy,&Ex,&Ey,&Fx,&Fy);

    s1 = fabs((Bx-Ax)*(Ay+By)+(Cx-Bx)*(Cy+By)+(Ax-Cx)*(Ay+Cy))/2;
    s2 = fabs((Ex-Dx)*(Dy+Ey)+(Fx-Ex)*(Fy+Ey)+(Dx-Fx)*(Dy+Fy))/2;

    if (s1 > s2 || fabs(s1-s2) <= 0.001) printf("1");
    else printf("2");

}
```